# Обработчик события у компонента Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня есть компонент ToolStripMenuItem в MenusStrip (назовем tool). Этот компонент подписан на событие Click с обработчиком событий Tool_Click.
Мне необходимо, зная только ссылку на компонент tool, подписать другой компонент на событие Click, но на этот же обработчик.

Еще раз уточняю, при условии, что я не могу использовать прямое название обработчика Tool_Click.
Как мне получить этот метод имея только tool.

Comment: Вам это не нужно. Вы решаете какую-то задачу. Какую? Опишите подробно и вам наверняка предложат решение без ненужных поисков обработчиков событий.

Comment: Могу предложить костыль: подпишите другой компонент на любое событие (собственный Click), внутри которого вызывайте метод `tool.PerformClick();` - это вызовет `Tool_Click`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov нет задание не учебное суть вот в чем: динамически создается элементы панели toolStrip(панель быстрого доступа) функционал, которой дублируется из выше расположенной строки меню. В итоге при динамическом создании элементов используется указатель на уже существующий пункт MenuStrip, т.е. при создании нового элемента берутся свойства уже существующего компонента. А т.к. в ToolStrip элементов может быть много, создаются они через foreach. А у всех уже существующих компонентов в MenuStrip, разные обработчики событий. Надеюсь понятно объяснил.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6055422/5045688 - годится? Попробуйте и отпишитесь.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Да этот способ работает отлично, спасибо)